# Mulesoft Amazon connector security

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I am using Anypoint Studio 7.3, Mule 4.1.5 and Amazon S3 connector 5.2

When I configure the Amazon S3 connector I have to set the access key and secret key.  My query is what other security is there around this connection e.g. how is the connection encrypted?  Is it safe for sensitive data?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation states, it uses the AWS APIs and the AWS SDK for Java. So it uses the security mechanisms provided by Amazon themselves.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/amazon/amazon-s3-connector